Installed KDE but didn't configured the display manager
I just installed kde-full and choose sddm as Display Manager after installation, but I didn't logged out and changed the desktop environment to KDE and just rebooted, now when I boot my Ubuntu I see a black screen.

Update:
The problem explained with a fix in Here
